# image upload using android multipart than getting error in old version

Tags: android

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode
     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.<init>(MultipartEntity.java:91)
     at com.greencubes.greendesk.AndroidMultiPartEntity.<init>(AndroidMultiPartEntity.java:19)
     at com.greencubes.greendesk.FirstFragment$UploadFileToServer.uploadFile(FirstFragment.java:244)
     at com.greencubes.greendesk.FirstFragment$UploadFileToServer.doInBackground(FirstFragment.java:233)
     at com.greencubes.greendesk.FirstFragment$UploadFileToServer.doInBackground(FirstFragment.java:211)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: what old version? what is your `targetSdk` and `compileSdk`? Post relevant code where you get the exception (Your `AsyncTask` class). http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: targetsdk:23 and  also compilesdk:23

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a library, you need to put it into /libs folder.
download httpmime, httpcore and httpclient library from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

Hope this will help as i have the same jar files in the studio.

If you are using Eclipse then add all the jar files to build path.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using studio or eclipse?

Comment: using android studio

Comment: is there any error while building project, any gradle error/exception?

Comment: no run android loliipop then run perfectly. but run in kitkat or jellybean than give error

Comment: oh ok then why dont you give this information when you post your question.

Answer (score 0):

Apache HTTP client was [removed in Lollipop](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client). It's recommended to use [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead.

If you have to use it you can add:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

to your build.gradle file.

Comment: @vipulparmar add the relevant code where you are getting the exception. Edit the question and add the code from the `AsyncTask`